# Delete non-distinct rows based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012. I have a table with thousands of rows of data in it. Many of the rows are duplicates, and I need to remove them. Each row has a unique identifier `[OwnerID]` which is set to Identity Specification with an Identity Increment of 1. For each row, the duplicates lie in these columns: `[FirstName]`, `[LastName]`, and `[CompanyName]`.

So I need to delete rows with duplicate combinations of values in these 3 columns. After the deletion, is there t-sql I can write to reset the Identity Specification in
`[OwnerID]` to start at 1 for the first row and assign values to the rest of the rows in increments of 1?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: it is very easy to do. What have you tried? I can give you some directions: First: create a select statement groupped by [FirstName], [LastName], and [CompanyName] and insert it to a temp table. Next, TRUNCATE your table. Then, insert into your truncated table data from the temp table. Drop the temp table afterwards. When you truncate the table, the identity resets

Comment: Why do you need to reset the identity and be careful with this.  If you reset them to be in sequence and they are used as in foreign keys for other tables then you've lost relationships. in addition if your deleting the duplicates and the duplicates have been used in relationships, the relationships may need to be set to the identify of the record which will remain.  Lots of risk here for what reward?

Comment: Okay, I forgot to add that there are foreign key relationships to other tables. The objective is to only have one row per unique Owner. Right now, since I have just imported a bunch of junk data, there are multiple rows with the same Owner `[FirstName]`, `[LastName]`, and `[CompanyName]`. I just need a way to delete these. I'm not sure how to go about it so I haven't tried anything yet. @Cha, could you be more specific in how I need to code this? And I guess i don't really need to reset identity specification, I just thought it might look cleaner.

Comment: ok, it looks like you really do not want to try it yourself. Use the sqlfiddle I have created (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4778/2) as a playground. Do not use the queries as suggested by Makhmoud, as you will end up without the duplicate entries at all!

Comment: @cha, thanks for the tip. I haven't ran the below query yet but will look at your sqlfiddle. Sorry I've never had to do this before (I'm fairly new to some of the sql commands), and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my try using the temporary tables [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f12d1/6):

```
SELECT 
firstName, LastName, CompanyName, COUNT(*) thecount, MIN(ID) min_id
INTO #temp
FROM tab
GROUP BY firstName, LastName, CompanyName;

SELECT 
a.id ID, b.min_id
INTO #temp1
FROM tab a, #temp b
WHERE  a.firstName  = b.FirstName 
AND a.LastName    = b.LastName
AND a.CompanyName = b.CompanyName
AND b.thecount > 1;

-- run this query on all referenced tables:
UPDATE tab2 SET tab2.ID = t.min_id
FROM tab2, #temp1 t
WHERE tab2.ID = t.ID;

DELETE t
FROM tab t, #temp1 a
WHERE t.id = a.id and a.id <> a.min_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to delete the rows, by using `row_number()` to keep the first one:

```
with todelete as (
    select t.*,
           row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname, companyname
                              order by ownerid) as seqnum
    from t
)
delete from todelete
    where seqnum = 1;
```

To reset the ownerid, you can also use a similar idea:

```
with toupdate as (
    select t.*, row_number() over (order by ownerid) as seqnum
    from t
   )
update toupdate
    set ownerid = seqnum;
```

However, you should be very careful with this.  In a well-designed database, a field called `OwnerID` would refer to a column in a table called either `Owner.OwnerId` or `Owner.Id`.  Changing the value of ids can have effects on other tables.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the duplicate data and keep one value use this query with seperated by commas for multiple columns

delete a from (
  select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by FirstName order by MemberId)
  from Membership 
) a
where rn > 1;